# subquery with table value function not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (id INT, NAME VARCHAR(20) )

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20) = '1,2'

INSERT INTO @temp (id, NAME)
VALUES (1, ''), (2, ''), (2, '')

SELECT * 
FROM @temp a
WHERE id IN ((SELECT String FROM dbo.FN_SplitStrings(@str,',')))
```

I'm getting the following error while running this

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type
>   int.

Code:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[FN_SplitStrings] 
( 
   @StringToSplit varchar(8000), 
   @Separator varchar(128)
) 
RETURN TABLE 
AS 
   RETURN 
     with indices as 
     ( 
        select 
            0 S, 1 E 
        union all 
        select 
            E, charindex(@Separator, @StringToSplit, E) + len(@Separator) 
        from 
            indices 
        where E > S
     ) 
     select 
         substring(@StringToSplit,S, case when E > len(@Separator) 
 then e-s-len(@Separator) else len(@StringToSplit) - s + 1 end) String ,
         S StartIndex 
     from 
         indices 
     where 
         S > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This splitting can be used without a function

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE
(
   id INT,
   NAME VARCHAR(20)
)

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20)='1,2'
INSERT INTO @temp
        ( id, NAME )
VALUES  ( 1, '' ),
         ( 2, ''),
         ( 2, '')

SELECT * FROM @temp a
 WHERE id IN 
 (
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'KeyWords' 
        FROM  
        (
             -- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
             SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@str, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data                
        ) AS A 
        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a9ad/1) to view the result

**EDIT:**

You had some problems in function for splitting.

**Function**

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_SplitStrings(@StringToSplit varchar(8000),@Separator char(1))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH splitter_cte AS (
      SELECT CHARINDEX(@Separator, @StringToSplit) as pos, 0 as lastPos
      UNION ALL
      SELECT CHARINDEX(@Separator, @StringToSplit, pos + 1), pos
      FROM splitter_cte
      WHERE pos > 0
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, lastPos + 1,
                     case when pos = 0 then 80000
                     else pos - lastPos -1 end) as String
    FROM splitter_cte
  )
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE (id INT, NAME VARCHAR(20) )

DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20) = '1,2'

INSERT INTO @temp (id, NAME)
VALUES (1, ''), (2, ''), (2, '')

SELECT * 
FROM @temp a
WHERE id IN ((SELECT String FROM dbo.FN_SplitStrings(@str,',')))
```

- **[Click here to view result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91b65/1)**

Comment: wanted to solve with table value function..thanks for your answer

Comment: Can u post the function? It may be because of an error in the function. @Mujahid

Comment: Above i have added the function which is been used

Comment: The function is used only for splitting strings right ? @Mujahid

Answer (score 0):

The reason is a mix in data types and the fact that your function is an inline table valued functions which means that it is embedded into the query before query optimization takes place.

If you remove `where S > 0` from your function and execute it with `1,2`, the result of the function is:

```
String
------
1,2
1
2
```

Notice the first row where the value is `1,2`.

When the optimizer does its job with your query the comparison against the column `id` is done before the where clause of the function is evaluated. In that comparison you have an implicit cast to `int` and `1,2` can not be casted to an `int`.

To fix this you can make sure that the String column of your split function is always an `int` (and perhaps changing the name of the column in the process).

```
 select 
     cast(substring(@StringToSplit,S, case when E > len(@Separator) 
                                   then e-s-len(@Separator) 
                                   else len(@StringToSplit) - s + 1 
                                 end) as int) String ,
```